# Use Constructor with Lambda expression (Set Comparator)

Tags: java, lambda, expression, comparator, treeset

I am given the task to use the constructor TreeSet(`Comparator<E> comparator`) with a lambda expression to make the set be sorted by book title.

The following information is given:

```
public class Book implements Comparable<Book> {
    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public int compareTo(Book obj) {
      return isbn.compareTo(obj.isbn);
    }
    // all-args constructor and getters
}
```

What I have thought about so far is:
I think that the constructor allows you to define the Comparator. Perhaps I should do:

```
Comparator<String> comp = 
    (String title, String obj.title) -> (title.compareTo(obj.title));
```

Then put this comp into the `TreeSet<Book> bookSet = new TreeSet<Book>(comp);`

However, that doesn't seem to work. I think what I need to do is use the lambda expression in the same row when creating the new TreeSet, however, I am unsure how to do so.

Comment: You want a `Comparator<Book>`, as it compares books, right?

Answer (score 5):

You need a `Comparator<Book>`, not a `Comparator<String>`. The easiest way to get one would be to use [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
TreeSet<Book> bookSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle));
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a *book* comparator. Even if you're going to compare by book title, you'll still have to use `Comparator<Book>`.

To reuse your code, the correction you need is:

```
Comparator<Book> comp = 
    (Book book1, Book book2) -> (book1.getTitle().compareTo(book2.getTitle()));
```

Which can be rewritten as

```
Comparator<Book> comp = 
    (book1, book2) -> (book1.getTitle().compareTo(book2.getTitle()));
```

Or

```
Comparator<Book> comp = Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle);
```

You can then pass `comp` as argument to `TreeSet`'s constructor

Answer (score 2):

**Book:**

```
public class Book {
  private String isbn;
  private String title;
  private String author;

  public Book(String isbn, String title, String author) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
  }

  public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
  }

  public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
  }

  public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Book{" + "isbn='" + isbn + '\'' + ", title='" + title + '\'' + ", author='" + author + '\'' + '}';
  }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book book1 = new Book("isbn1", "First Book", "Author 1");
    Book book2 = new Book("isbn2", "Second Book", "Author 2");
    Book book3 = new Book("isbn3", "Third Book", "Author 3");

    //Method first
    Set<Book> books1 = new TreeSet<>((book, thisBook) -> book.getTitle().compareTo(thisBook.getTitle()));

    books1.add(book3);
    books1.add(book2);
    books1.add(book1);

    //Method second
    Set<Book> books2 = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle));

    books2.add(book2);
    books2.add(book1);
    books2.add(book3);

    System.out.println(books1);
    System.out.println(books2);

  }
}
```

As you are inserting values into a `set` so I recommend you to add `hashcode` and `equals` method in `Book` class as well to identify the unique book object.